# Properties use if - else on set? or on get?

Tags: c#, class, dependency-properties

Is a performance question, i am using a class like example below:
I have two properties Status and Price.

```
public class Customers
{
    public bool Status {get; set;} 
    public string Price {get; set;} 

}
```

So i am confused i need to check if status is true or false and then to return a string format in price. My question is which of two methods has better performance. Or if performance is insignificant.

#Example 1

```
public class Customers
{
    public bool Status {get; set;} 
    public string Price
    {
          return status ? 
             string.Format("{0:0.00}", Price) + "€" :
             "Item Status is False";
    }

}
```

#Example 2

```
public class Customers
{
    private string priceAsString;

    public bool Status {get; set;} 
    public string Price
    {
        get
        {
            return priceAsString;
        }
        set
        {
            priceAsString= Status?
                string.Format("{0:0.00}", Price) + "€" :
                "Item Status is False";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: The second variant doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Thank you General so you more preferable way is the Example 1 right?

Comment: The first way seems like a stackoverflow exception waiting to happen

Comment: In your second example, what do you expect to happen if *Status* changes after `Price` is set? However, your first example doesn't compile either, so neither is obviously better. As in the linked post, prefer *simple*, correctly working code before worrying about performance.

Comment: A comment to the second solution: What is if `Status` Changes after `Price` was set?
The performance in these two examples is really insignificant. You should go for the more readable and better maintainable... so you should go for version 1. As a side note: the code of the first version does not compile.

Comment: the set method won't be called. you should assign a value to be called. it doesn't make sense. but you can assign (priceAsString) a value when you change (Status) value so wherever you check the value of (Price) you'll find it ready for you.

Comment: For my needs status will never change after first population

Comment: I am guessing you want something like this `public string DisplayPrice => Status ? $"{Price:0.00}€" : "Item Status is False";`